# Find what file a short lived HANDLE is associated with

Tags: winapi, reverse-engineering, handle, ida

I am playing around with the demo of IDA and I am trying to do some reverse engineering of a program to figure out the structure of one of its files that it uses. My final goal is to be able to read that file directly from my own program.

Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) I was able to find the subroutine that calls `kernel32_ReadFile`. What I would like to know is how do I find out what the `hFile` variable is pointing to before it makes the call to `ReadFile`

I have been exploring around the menus while in debug mode and I have not found anywhere inside IDA where I can look up information about what file is associated with a file handle.

How do I map a handle to a real file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MSDN page describes ways to get the file name from a file handle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789(v=vs.85).aspx

Is that the information you were looking for?  I'm not sure why you can't see the the file name directly in Process Monitor.

Comment: That is what I am doing but I want to do a conditional breakpoints if a specific file is being read. I found a work around though, I can break on 'nNumberOfBytesToRead == 259' as that is uniuqe to the file I want. I won't accept yet as I would like a solution for how to do it inside IDA, but I will give you the answer if no one gives a solution in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a breakpoint on `CreateFileA` and `CreateFileW` and see what files are being opened.  You can then match the returned `HANDLE` value to the subsequent `ReadFile` call.